# prediction using linear model and the importance of data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, prediction, lm

I am writing to ask why should we add data.frame() to predict by using lm

the first chunk of code is supposed to be wrong and the second chunk of code is supposed to be correct.

```
dim(iris)
model_1<-lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width, data=iris)
summary(model_1)
print(predict(model_1, Sepal.Width=c(1,3,4,5)))
```

```
dim(iris)
model_1<-lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width, data=iris)
summary(model_1)
print(predict(model_1,data.frame(Sepal.Width=c(1,3,4,5))))
```

Comment: because `predict` expects second argument i.e. `newdata` to be a dataframe. Check `?predict` for more help

Comment: It has to do with environments. `lm` evaluates the new data in a certain environment. From `help('lm')`, section Details (my emphasis): *predict.lm produces predicted values, obtained by evaluating the regression function in the **frame** newdata (which defaults to model.frame(object)).*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `predict` on a `lm` object, the function called is [predict.lm](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/lm.R). When you run it like:

```
predict(model_1, Sepal.Width=c(1,3,4,5))
```

What you are doing is providing `c(1,3,4,5)` an argument or parameter to  `Sepal.Width`, which `predict.lm` ignores since this argument does not exist for this function.

When there is no new input data, you are running `predict.lm(model_1)`,  and getting back the fitted values:

```
table(predict(model_1) == predict(model_1, Sepal.Width=c(1,3,4,5)))

TRUE 
 150
```

In this case, you fitted the model with a formula, the `predict.lm` function needs your data frame to reconstruct the independent or exogenous matrix, matrix multiply with the coefficients and return you the predicted values.

This is briefly what `predict.lm` is doing:

```
newdata = data.frame(Sepal.Width=c(1,3,4,5))
Terms = delete.response(terms(model_1))
X = model.matrix(Terms,newdata)

X
  (Intercept) Sepal.Width
1           1           1
2           1           3
3           1           4
4           1           5

X %*% coefficients(model_1)
      [,1]
1 6.302861
2 5.856139
3 5.632778
4 5.409417

predict(model_1,newdata)

       1        2        3        4 
6.302861 5.856139 5.632778 5.409417
```